# How to pass variable into to_char()

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I try to create a function to delete records older than certain number of days.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION delete_records(num_days int)
RETURNS void AS 
$BODY$
DECLARE 
   DATE timestamp; 
   sqlsatement text; 
BEGIN 
  select to_char((now() - interval 'num_days  day'), 'YYYY-MM-DD') into DATE;
  sqlsatement  := format ('DELETE FROM A_Table WHERE A_DATE < ''%s''', DATE)
  EXECUTE sqlsatement  ;
END; 
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Error:

```
postgres=# select delete_records(89);
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type interval: "num_days  day"
LINE 1: select to_char((now() - interval 'num_days  day'), 'YYYY-MM-...
                                         ^
```

Answer (score 3):

You should not convert a timestamp into a varchar if you plan to store it in a `timestamp` variable (and then compare it to a timestamp column).

To generate an interval of days based on the parameter, you can use the `make_interval()` function:

```
date := current_timestamp - make_interval(days => num_days);
```

But you are over-complicating things. You don't need any variable or dynamic SQL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION delete_records(num_days int)
RETURNS void AS 
  DELETE FROM A_Table 
  WHERE A_DATE < current_timestamp - make_interval(days => num_days);
$BODY$
LANGUAGE sql;
```

If you simplified your example and you really, really do need dynamic SQL, then don't concatenate values into the string:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION delete_records(num_days int)
RETURNS void AS 
$BODY$
DECLARE 
   sqlsatement text; 
BEGIN 
  sqlsatement := 'DELETE FROM A_Table WHERE A_DATE < $1'
  EXECUTE sqlsatement 
    using current_timestamp - make_interval(days => num_days);
END; 
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

---

<sup>(I find a variable named `date` with the type `timestamp` highly confusing)</sup>